# Sitecore 6.4: User Profile Start URL and Workbox

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a requirement to present the user the Workbox when logging into the sitecore administration interface. I've identified that this can be done by setting the user profile Start URL to /sitecore/shell/applications/workbox.aspx.
This works - when the user logs in they get the workbox, but the Logoff link is missing from the top menu (which is there when you access the workbox via the Content Editor - but I notice not if you access it via the Menu item).

Is there any way of getting this Logoff button back, or adding a custom one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've checked it in Sitecore 6.6 and there is no logout button in workbox by default as well.

The fix for this is very easy. Login to the Sitecore desktop, switch to the 'core' database, open the Content Editor and navigate to the node:

```
/sitecore/content/Applications/Workbox/Ribbon/Home/Write/Logoff
```

There is a field 'Click' with value 'workbox:logout'. Just change the value to 'system:logout' and the logout button will be there.

Comment: Thanks Maras! Much appreciated! Totally forgot that it would be under Applications in Core.